# Spring Aggregator Aggregate groups of input

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I want to aggregate data into groups, how can I do that? I would like to use the aggregator (Spring Integration) for this. My scenario looks like this.

```
Spring Batch<-->Spring Integration File -->Reader-->Proccessor<-->[Gateway<->Aggregator]
```

---

```
{Male,Joe;Male,Dave;Female,Anne;Female,Jane}-->sequentialyto-->Gateway-->Aggregate-> Gender(Male,{Joe,Dave}...Gender{Female,{Anne,Jane})
```

what does the release strategy look like? I Need small Code snippets

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is `Reader` in your case, but Spring Integration provides a `FileSplitter` tool. Its `markers` you can use to determine that aggregator is ready to release.

I would say that you need to have a `releaseStrategy` as `false`:

```
release-strategy-expression="false"
```

That means your groups won't be released under the normal conditions. You can't determine the size of the group to be ready to release.

The `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END` emitted as the last message from the `FileSplitter` after reading the last line of the file together with the `MessageGroupStore.expireMessageGroups(0)` call would make that aggregator working well. However need still to configure:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="send-partial-result-on-expiry" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                    Specifies whether messages that expired should be aggregated and sent to the 'output-channel' or 'replyChannel'.
                    Messages are expired when their containing MessageGroup expires. One of the ways of expiring MessageGroups is by
                    configuring a MessageGroupStoreReaper. However MessageGroups can alternatively be expired by simply calling
                    MessageGroupStore.expireMessageGroups(timeout). That could be accomplished via a ControlBus operation
                    or by simply invoking that method if you have a reference to the MessageGroupStore instance.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
```

To release groups normally after that expiration.